# Displaying values in FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf-generation, fpdf

This is my code for generating pdf using FPDF in php. I want to display the semester, bill month and the billyear in the PDF file. I dont want to display the values in the table.
I want to display at the top of the page. How can i do this? Any suggestion? Thanks in advance. Cheers.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

    //Connect to your database

    $r1=$_SESSION['sem1'];

    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

    if(!$con)
    {
    die('Unable to connect'.mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('hostel',$con);

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT r.hosteladmissionno,
           r.student_name,
           r.semester,
           r.blockname
           r.branch,
           m.billmonth,m.billyear ,
           (s.days_mess*perdayrate) AS mess_charges,
           m.perdayrate,
           s.days_mess,s.nv_tokens
           FROM registration r,student_month s,messexp m
           WHERE  s.hosteladmissionno = r.hosteladmissionno 
           AND r.mess_type=m.messtype
           AND m.billmonth = 'March' AND m.billyear= '2014'");
         $number_of_products = mysql_numrows($result);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $hostad = $row['hosteladmissionno'];
        $name = $row['student_name'];
        $block=$row['blockname'];
        $branch=$row['branch'];
        $perday=$row['perdayrate'];
        $days=$row['days_mess'];
        $messch= $row['mess_charges'];
        $nv=$row['nv_tokens'];




        $column_no = $column_no.$hostad."\n";
        $column_name = $column_name.$name."\n";
        $sem_details= $sem_details.$block."\n";
        $comm_details= $comm_details.$branch."\n";
        $course_details= $course_details.$perday."\n";
        $courseyr_details= $courseyr_details.$days."\n";
        $mess_details= $mess_details.$messch."\n";
        $block_details= $block_details.$nv."\n";



    }
    mysql_close();

    //Create a new PDF file
    $pdf=new FPDF('P','mm','A4');

    $pdf->AddPage();

    //Fields Name position
    $Y_Fields_Name_position = 40;
    //Table position, under Fields Name
    $Y_Table_Position = 46;
    $pdf->Cell(15,50,'Anna University Hostels');
    //First create each Field Name
    //Gray color filling each Field Name box
    $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
    //Bold Font for Field Name
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
    $pdf->SetX(5);
    $pdf->Cell(23,6,'Admission No',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->SetX(28);
    $pdf->Cell(37,6,'Student Name',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->SetX(65);
    $pdf->Cell(18,6,'Block Name',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->SetX(83);
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Branch',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->SetX(103);
    $pdf->Cell(22,6,'Per Day Rate',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->SetX(125);
    $pdf->Cell(22,6,'No of Days',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->SetX(147);
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Mess charge',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->SetX(167);
    $pdf->Cell(18,6,'NV Token',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->SetX(185);
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,'Block Name',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Ln();

    //Now show the 3 columns
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
    $pdf->SetX(5);
    $pdf->MultiCell(23,6,$column_no,1);
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
    $pdf->SetX(28);
    $pdf->MultiCell(37,6,$column_name,1);
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
    $pdf->SetX(65);
    $pdf->MultiCell(18,6,$block,1);
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
    $pdf->SetX(83);
    $pdf->MultiCell(20,6,$branch,1);
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
    $pdf->SetX(103);
    $pdf->MultiCell(22,6,$perday,1);
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
    $pdf->SetX(125);
    $pdf->MultiCell(22,6,$days,1);
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
    $pdf->SetX(147);
    $pdf->MultiCell(20,6,$messch,1);
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
    $pdf->SetX(167);
    $pdf->MultiCell(18,6,$nv,1);
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
    $pdf->SetX(185);
    $pdf->MultiCell(25,6,$block_details,1);
    $i = 0;
    $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
    while ($i < $number_of_products)
    {
        $pdf->SetX(5);
        $pdf->MultiCell(205,6,'',1);
        $i = $i +1;
    }
    $pdf->Output();
    ?>
```

Comment: Pretty much the same thing as you are already doing...  find the X/Y of where you do want it, add a cell...

Comment: Im not able to display it when i create a seperate cell, its returning error.

Comment: @Dinzy: `Cell()` is returning an error?  Are you passing invalid parameters to it?

Comment: @orbling, Thanks i re located the X/Y postions and made that coming.

Comment: Not that I want to criticise at all, FPDF is not so bad but definitely not the most recommended lib for PDF`s.  Especially if you ever need Unicode support. It's quite old and not maintained.  TcPDF is a fork of FPDF that has a lot of bug-fixes and more features.

Comment: Have you thought about using one of the various PDF converters out there? I tend to use either HTML2PS or DOMPDF - you create an HTML file and pass it to the library, which builds the PDF for you. Much easier cos you can use things like smarty templates to help...

Comment: @steffgosselin +1 TCPDF also has a `Header` method where you can define a per-page header. In combination with FPDI you can also load templates and only alter the parts needed. Don't know about FPDF though, maybe it's there as well..

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use the standard "header()" extend function of FPDF ? 
http://fpdf.org/en/doc/header.htm

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code between line `$Y_Table_Position = 46` and line `$pdf->Cell(15,50,'Anna University Hostels');`, It will display "Semester,Month,Year" color gray in the right top of your page (change Semester,Month,Year with their real values).

```
    //Fields Name position
    $Y_Fields_Name_position = 40;
    //Table position, under Fields Name
    $Y_Table_Position = 46;
// ABOVE IS YOUR ORIGINAL CODE, ADD The FOLOWING LINES

    $pdf->SetXY(160,0);
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',6);
    $pdf->SetTextColor('139','140','142');
    $pdf->Cell(5,15,'Semester,Month,Year',0,0,'L');

    $pdf->SetTextColor('0','0','0');
    $pdf->SetXY(16,8);

// CONTINUE WITH ORIGINAL CODE
    $pdf->Cell(15,50,'Anna University Hostels');
    //First create each Field Name
    //Gray color filling each Field Name box
    $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
```

As you see I go to X=160, Y=0 and create a new Cell with the desired text, custom font and color, after that, I change the color to black (beacause my default font color is white) and go to X=16,Y=8 so your "Anna University Hostels" is printed in the same position. After that you're table will be printed as before.

Hope I understad your question, and this is what you're looking for. (if not leave a comment :) )

Answer (score 1):

Set up the stuff you talked about in the header function.

```
function header()
{
     $this->SetFont('whatever the font u like','B',23)//I just randomly set fonts
     $this->Cell(30,10,'$_POST['user_id']',0,0,'C');
     ...
     ...
}
```