# PHP Mysql Export to pdf

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, export

I have millions of data to be exported to pdf.
I am not able to do that.
Please suggest me the way.
Using inbuilt header(Content-type: application/pdf) is not resolving my problem.
I have also tried using TCPDF.With less data tcpdf works fine but with millions it takes very very long time.

Tell me a way where I can easily export mysql data that counts to millions exported in pdf.

Comment: Are you talking about millions of rows?

Comment: How are you attempting to create this export (e.g. via web site or command-line code)? What is the export format (e.g. tabular)? You're talking about a significant amount of data, so a commercial solution might be in order. Barring that, you might have to create each page (or a batch of pages) separately then join them together to prevent significant resource usage and process slowdown.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/). Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454969/displaying-values-in-fpdf) might help you.

Comment: This is not an answer in any way

Comment: @Shakti -- poster suggested a php class which could be used to solved Mukta's problem, plus a link to a post which gives an example of how to use the class. Seems like a pretty complete and concise answer to me!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Data Import (PDF format) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). There is command-line support, that I think you could use in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you move all data to text file and then you can install any application in linux like this ( http://www.eprg.org/pdfcorner/text2pdf/ )

and now use [php exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and use command line of text2pdf in run faster than php

also see this link

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/command-line-text-to-pdf-conversion-290058/
- [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) its python library and you can use it like command line with python commands